# Socket Io - Emitting to a room or individual sockets performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am building a chat messaging application using Socket Io and Node js. Currently, whenever a user loads the app, they are connected to their own room, with their user Id (coming from the database) as the room name. This is so I can handle sending events to particular users in my application. The code for this looks as follows:

`socket.join(user.userId);`

Users can create chats, which can contain 2 or more users. When a chat is created, so is a `room`. Currently, whenever a user sends a message, an event is emitted to the entire room like so:

`io.to('chatname').emit('Chat message', msg)`

However the problem I have is that I only allow users to join the chat rooms whenever they click on the **chat page**. This means that they wouldn't receieve the new messsage if they were on a different page as they wouldn't be a part of that room. I want users to still receieve messages, regardless of the current page they are on.

A solution to this would be sending message events to a users personal socket (the room they join when they connect), instead of sending the event to the room like the code above. This would look like this:

```
users.forEach(user => {
    
 // Sending to indivdual users room which they join when connecting.  
 // This would replace the code above, therefore all messages would be sent directly to the users personal room instead of the actual chat room.
 io.to(user.userId).emit('Chat message', msg)
})
```

I am wondering whether this code is less efficient than sending to the `room` itself like I am currently doing, due to having to loop over each user and sending the event to their individual room. Is sending directly to the room better practise and more performant? Also, could joining the user to their own room be inefficient due to the fact that socket io already joins users to their own room, with the name being their `socket id`? I do this so it is easier to send events to specific users, however is this considered bad practise? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

my advise is.

1. rooms should be unique and separate from users
2. rooms should contain users
3. on your app (frontend) allow the user to signin/authenticate with you backend
4. once authed, give the users a list of all current rooms.
5. also allow the user to create a new room, whether there is rooms or there are no rooms in that list
6. each room should have an `owner`, so when a room is created, set the `owner_id` to be the `user_id` of the created user
7. then allow the user to click on an existing or their own chat, allowing them to join the room
8. you could save in the database which user's are in each room.
9. when a user is viewing a `room` you can just use nodejs with socket to communicate each message to said room users, also add the message to the database. so that when a users first joins and starts the initial viewing of the room will then receive a bulk messages, so that their chat view will be caught up to the actual chat room.

## Recap

DB Tables

```
Room:
   ID
   Name
   Owner_ID

RoomUsers:
   ID
   User_ID
   Room_ID

User:
   ID
   Name
   Email
   Password

Message:
   ID
   Room_ID
   Sender_ID
   Message
```

Comment: But when emitting message events, instead of emitting to a room, could I also alternatively send the event to each individual user as I want them to receive messages even if they are not on the chat page (to indicate there is a new message )

Comment: yes you could do that, or, you can just monitor when a user is in a chat room, and if they are not in a chat room just send them an event, and on the client just count the events for each room the user is not in, then display a little read circle with a number inside it to indicate that there are X unread messages

Comment: so just to verify, you are suggesting to always emit new chat messages to the actual rooms, however also send a event(like a notification) so if a user is not currently in the chat, they can still receive the new message event

Comment: this method would include sending two separate events. A notification event as well as a message event. Also, on the server when emitting the events, how would you distinguish whether the user is in the chat or not, or are you suggesting to send two events whenever a message is sent

Comment: no, not 2 events, just one event. your client should have concurrent connections to each room, and on the client side, just check if the user is actively in the room (client state) and then if they are load the message and display them, else if not in the room then just show a counter, which you can calculate from each message recieved.

Comment: discord uses an approach like this on the discrod client app

Comment: add me on discord, then we can chat and I can assist you with your project my user is  `thex3r0`

Comment: I think I understand. One quick thing is in terms of concurrent connections, do you mean ensuring a user is listening to all rooms they are a part of as soon as they join the socket server, and then determine whether they are in that room currently or not? Is this what you’re suggesting? Thanks

Comment: yes, you can do one of two ways, 1. handle all events sent for each room through one socket connection, or 2. have each room have its own socket connection. 

option 1 uses less memory, but may be slower, option 2 may be faster but uses more memory... play with both ideas and see what fits your needs

Comment: Ok, final thing is how would I go about option 1? What would the code for the implementation look like? Would I need to create a room which links to all existing rooms? If not, what would the code/approach look like for this? Thanks

Comment: redo how you are designing your system. plan it out on paper with flow diagrams, and then code it

Comment: @samalvis here is a little design for you https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Y-4uSSWf6Vr1eKGOm4rbvSOrIyjhxucBgkG6BxZcf5c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much I greatly appreciate your support. On the diagram, when sending a message and connecting to all rooms, does this mean connect to all rooms the user is a part of on the root level, and listen to new message events for each room?

Comment: @samalvis yes, thats 100% correct.

Comment: Ah so when the user first connects, automatically join them to all the rooms/chats they are a part of so they can retrieve the events from the rooms. If the user had 100 rooms/chats, would automatically joining them all when a user connects to the socket server  not be inefficient, due to the sheer amount of potential rooms/chats they would have to automatically join when first connecting ?

Comment: thats why you can connect between each, or to all of them, its your choice

Comment: ok thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an architectural rather than a programmatic issue. I suggest that you maintain the state between the client and the server. This means that each user can still recieve information on any room they join as long as they haven't performed an action to leave a room such as clicking a "Leave room" button.
Your first solution which is:

```
io.to('chatname').emit('Chat message', msg)
```

is the correct implementation. So this is most likely an issue of storing state and architecture.

Comment: Ok, but for this to work, I would need to ensure that each user has actually joined the room when the application starts. This means automatically joining them to every room/chat that they are a part of when first connecting. I need to do this to ensure they have joined the room and can receive messages from rooms even if they haven't entered the chat section of the application. If there was 100 chats/rooms, automatically joining this many rooms when first connecting would be inefficient though right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You just need to keep track of your users rooms and chat details on the server-side of things.

Comment: ok so to clarify, automatically join all rooms a user is a part of when initially connecting, and there is no problem doing this right